# Touch Screen Password Guessing by Fingerprint Trace

Tags: passwords, mobile

After eating some garlic bread at a friend's who is **not** security-aware, she managed to quickly determine the PIN code to unlock the screen of my Samsung SIII.

She figured this out by simply holding the device against the light and looking at the grease pattern my thumb left on the screen. It only took her 2 attempts to unlock the screen.

I guess she would not have been able to access my phone if I had kept the screen cleaner, or if the device could only be unlocked by pressing numbers, rather than dragging the finger to form a pattern.

Is this a common means of attack? Are finger dragging pattern passwords really more insecure than number touch passwords?

Comment: Having a complex pattern might gives more protection ...
having just simple line or a square like shapes reduces the possibilities for brute forcing . so so having a pattern like infinity sign is a good idea i think

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it's always great to see how security can sometimes be defeated almost by accident.

Comment: @HSN. Good point, specially because it becomes more difficult to trace where the pattern starts from. Though I am not sure how much this would actually deter someone from guessing as there is no such a thing as account lockout for multiple failed attempts.

Comment: "My security keypad will actually be a fingerprint scanner. Anyone who watches someone press a sequence of buttons or dusts the pad for fingerprints then subsequently tries to enter by repeating that sequence will trigger the alarm system." - Evil Overlord List

Comment: My 8 year old did the same thing with my SIII; I hastily reverted to a PIN ;-)

Comment: My Galaxy *was* stolen, and the guy who stole it *did* break into my phone exactly in this manner. Fortunately, he didn't manage to do further damage before I changed my Google passwords.

Comment: Related: I tried a pattern login for my Android device, but soon changed back to a PIN, not because of smudges but because it was much easier for a shoulder-surfer (our kids) to see and remember a shape than a series of taps on a number pad.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in some games, like Splinter Cell, smudge attack on door's security lock was used for protagonist to gain access — had to wait for the bodygoard to enter the code and pass through the door, then with the use of flashlight I was able to figure it out in three attempts.

Comment: Why was there a recent edit to this question? I looked at the edits and it feels unnecessary and a matter of stylistic preference over actually providing anything new here.

Comment: @Frank B Hmmm, I have no idea why he decided to change it. Although he stripped off my clumsy syntax and charming semantic foreignism, I must admit: it is better.

Comment: Another reason to concentrate on your food while eating, instead of taking playing with Instagram!

Comment: As an aside, this "attack" can work also fairly well on physical keypads whose code is not regularly changed. Where I used to live, it was quite easy to see which four keys on the entry-code keypad were used, which leaves only 24 possible guesses to brute-force.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is known as a 'Smudge Attack'

It really depends on how much you've used your phone since you've last unlocked it, but the general principle still stands. If you use the pattern feature of Android phones, this can be particularly obvious.

The University of Pennsylvania published a [research paper](http://static.usenix.org/events/woot10/tech/full_papers/Aviv.pdf) on the topic and basically concluded that they could figure out the password over 90 percent of the time.

The study also found that “pattern smudges,” which build up from writing the same password numerous times, are particularly recognizable.

Furthermore:

> “We showed that in many situations full or partial pattern recovery is
>   possible, even with smudge ‘noise’ from simulated application usage or
>   distortion caused by incidental clothing contact,”

While this is a plausible risk, It is not a particularly practical vulnerability as an attacker needs physical access to your phone. Using a PIN Code over a pattern may *reduce* the chance of this presenting a threat but it still exists depending on the strength of your PIN and the cleanliness of your hands/screen. However, these same researchers postulate another possible attack using the heat residue left by contact between your fingers and the screen which would be another problem altogether.

Obviously, cleaning your screen after every use is a practical (and not too difficult) defense against this specific attack. I'd expect that if you have used your phone (say to make calls/send a message/any kind of web browsing) it would also sufficiently obfuscate the patterns/codes. From examining my screen this seems to be the case.

Comment: No worries. I remember this attack quite well from this research paper. I like @AJHenderson frequently wipe my screen as a result :)

Comment: "90 percent", that's worrying. And interesting: it also means that most people's patterns are probably not very complex and thus bruteforceable.

Comment: @Luc I've seen two patterns that are almost un-replicatable even when I've been told the code. You can actually get between the points for the pattern codes and as a result, can make codes quite tricky...

Comment: @Luc: I think it would be reduced if the patterns allowed a start and end point to be the same, thus increasing the number of possible patterns per smudge trace from 2 (forward-backward) to 2(N-1). Needless to say...not surprised.

Comment: "Obviously, cleaning your screen after every use is a practical (and not to difficult) defense against this specific attack"... especially after garlic bread.

Comment: Note that the smudge attack risk also varies with the type of cover the device has. Some devices have covers that contact the screen effectively obfuscating the residue

Comment: @SébastienRenauld; I'm not sure how you reason here. Given a smudge trace it is quite easily detectable where the start/end points are. If they overlap, it would still only require two tries, even for circles and similar shapes. Also keep in mind that with smudge attacks, it is even possible to tell the direction in which the swipe was made leading to a single try that would be sufficient, given that the smudge trace is clear enough.

Comment: @Mythio: This depends on the finger of the individual. I have nearly indiscernable traces on my TF300T due to naturally *very* greasy fingers. However, that's just me. My point was mostly a side point - they could add a couple of multiples in patterns by allowing overlaps.

Comment: I also challenge anyone to get the smudged code off my phone after its been in my pocket next to my sweaty balls for a few hours...

Comment: randomizing the onscreen password entry key positions would solve this, although it would make entering the password a bit trickier.

Answer (score 40):

One way to mitigate [smudge attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smudge_attack) on smart phones is with an application called [WhisperCore](https://www.whispersystems.org/). It arranges the numbers vertically and it then asks you to wipe the screen in order to unlock the phone, obfuscating the original smudges.

[image]

If you use a pattern to lock your phone, after you input the correct pattern, it a screen full of stars. Swipe the highlighted stars to unlock the phone, again obfuscating the original smudge pattern.

[image]

Of course, the application basically works as a mandatory reminder to wipe your screen, but it's doing it in a way that makes less annoying to wipe your screen every time you unlock your phone.

Image source: [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/06/02/new-app-whispercore-prevents-smudge-attacks-on-android-phones-with-the-sacrifice-of-convenience-that-is/)

Comment: I've personally had a lot of problems with WhisperCore and the associated tools. I tried getting it running on several Android devices a few months ago to no avail. Things might be different now however.

Comment: Nice to see someone already made the application I suggested in my answer.  Will have to check it out.

Comment: Wait a second. Why not just shuffle the numbers on the first screen, and then ask to input a PIN? Then there's no need for the 2nd screen that requires a wipe.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley Because we, human beings, suck at remembering meaningless combinations of letters and numbers. That's why after using your phone for a couple of weeks you stop _actually_ typing your PIN and you start performing a series of touches on the screen that your muscles has "remembered". Same happens with your Operating System's password, because you type it several times a day, you just make quick strikes on the keyboard without thinking about the actual characters of your password. Now imagine if someone switched your keyboard's layout settings (Google German or Nordic layout).

Comment: @Adnan Speak for yourself.  Even with common long term passwords I enter them by repeating the mnemonic I memorized in lieu of something like "ASfy#wcltp13tbrtMIM".  Having to hunt/peck on an Qwertz/Azerty/Dvorak/etc keyboard would slow me down; but what I memorize isn't the positions of the keys.

Comment: @DanNeely I don't have to, science speaks for me. It's inevitable, whether you believe in it or not, repetitive tasks create new connections in your brain. Combined with a process called 'implicit learning', you learn how to ride a bike, how to drive a car, martial arts, the position of the light switch when you enter a dark room in your house, and your password. The norm with complex passwords is muscle memory, the exception is people like you (This is, of course, not to see that we forget our passwords completely). http://bit.ly/NZDMbQ , http://bit.ly/184ztVn , http://bit.ly/13zMyFf .

Comment: Yeah - I use muscle memory for most of my passwords, especially the long ones. In fact for some on PC's I know I have typed them correctly because of the noise!

Comment: @RoryAlsop Same here. I can't recite many passwords, or even recognize them from sight. Muscle memory all the way. Seeing them for the first time is like "Oh so that's what kept my account safe over the past months... wait quickly get it off the screen before I remember it!"

Answer (score 15):

There was a paper (will try and find it) that gave a very good explanation of a security improvement:

**Using one of the digits at least twice, in a pass code of more than 4 digits**

Basically, the "swipe a pattern" option is very easy to see - even at a distance it can be shoulder surfed. Have a look at **[this paper](http://static.usenix.org/events/woot10/tech/full_papers/Aviv.pdf)** for some interesting information on techniques.

A 4 digit pin is what most users end up choosing, if they use the pin option, so it is what most attackers will try, and holding the phone up to the light lets you see the pin quite clearly. If however you have a 6 digit pin where 2 of the digits are used twice, the attack space becomes quite challenging, as the attacker doesn't know whether you use a 4 digit pin, a 5 or even more - they are likely to start with a 4 and are more likely to lock the phone than get into it.

Answer (score 12):

This would be a good reason for another method of unlocking that made the unlocking action different every time. For example, instead of the numbers 0-9 being laid out as:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
  0
```

it might display them as:

```
3 5 7
1 2 4
6 9 0
  8
```

Instead of numbers, you could use shapes. Instead of just hitting the shapes or numbers, you could rearrange them into the correct pattern, though that would be less secure as it would be displaying the correct pattern immediately before it is unlocked; However, if the goal were to put the numbers in the matrix into an order where sums, etc. of certain rows were correct, that might be even more secure/less obvious to those that saw or recorded you performing the unlocking sequence.

Possibly for those only visually impaired, it could read the numbers out loud (through their headphones). For those that are visually impaired and hearing impaired, the phone could vibrate in a certain way when they touch different parts of the phone to determine which number is which, then they touch something once they know which number is where to enter the code. You could also have it lock the numbers into a certain orientation and only change on a predetermined schedule to make it less difficult to have to remember the new orientation, or even lock it completely, even though that would be susceptible to smudge attack.

Comment: I like this idea, but it may reduce usability for impaired users. It could also be problematic for long passwords or larger input alphabets. Having this be optional with it turned on by default seems like a good feature.

Comment: It wouldn't be fair to have them more susceptible to attack. I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: +1 for how this could work for impaired people.

Comment: There are a few companies that make keypads with LEDs in the keys that do exactly what you described.  The first time I saw one was in the 1990s, so it's not a new thing.  I have a friend who founded a (now-defunct) company called GrIDSure that, inspired by those locks, had a system where your PIN was a pattern and randomization of the keypad served turned it into a OTP.

Comment: Cyanogenmod actually has this feature where the layout of the numbers is randomized every time. Unfortunately it takes a lot longer to enter the pin..

Answer (score 10):

I for one have always wiped my screen on my shirt after unlocking it specifically because of this (and because I find the finger swipe marks annoying.)  But yes, this is very much a risk if you unlock it and don't at least continue to use it for a while to mess up the markings.

A pin code might help some, but you might still be able to see the spots touched which would greatly reduce the complexity of guessing the password.  It's still a good idea to wipe the screen if there are visible markings.

Another good counter for this would be if they added a second quick step to trace another pattern that would make recognizing the pattern more difficult before unlocking.

Comment: If available, a pinpad unlock screen that randomized the number layout each time would defeat a smudge attack.  Where I work the badgereaders we have do this; it only takes an extra second or two to find where the numbers are this time and type the 6 digit pin.  OTOH if all you have is a standard length pin an attacker could use brute force tools to break in and I suspect a scrambled layout would be a much larger impediment on an alphabetic keyboard if you were entering a password instead.

Comment: Someone needs to sell a line of shirts with built-in microfiber pads for wiping mobile device screens. :-)

Comment: @LarsH - maybe they could make it like the little tag with the product information, you could just flip it out, use it and then put it away.  Or we could bring back wearing a hankerchief in the breast pocket, but instead have a micro-fiber cloth. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I've wiped down my screen every time I turn it on for quite some time. It's partly due to this problem and partly to increase readability in the presence of glare. I was very interested to find out there is actual research out there on the topic.

While touch screens are especially prone to the problem of physical residue revealing secret information (despite the improvements that have been made in oleophobic screen coatings), **the problem can also occur with other input methods**. Fingerprints may be visible on the surface of (hardware) buttons, switches, or keypads, even without the use of specialized equipment.

Even if they're wiped down, however, there's a more permanent problem. I'm sure we've all seen text that has been rubbed off, membrane overlay that has ripped, or plating that is wearing down on a frequently used button:

[image: worn keypad]

In a security context, this type of problem likely means that the password is not being changed often enough, but I've seen real examples of it. Obviously it needs to be changed out before this degradation becomes visible to the naked eye. In higher security settings, though, that's probably not enough. Two possible remediations are to use very durable buttons and to even out the number of presses of every button either before or after entering the password.

Answer (score 4):

I use all ten digits exactly once in a ten-digit pin on my tablet, versus a pattern.  I also don't keep anything of particular value on my tablet (the only reason the password is there as a PIN is mandatory to save VPN configuration details with Android -- not including my user password).

Note: using a permutation of all ten digits exactly once does significantly cut down on the entropy.  The # of permutations: 10! = 3 628 800, which is roughly equivalent to a 6.56 character-long pin, or about 3000 times easier than a 10 digit random pin.

Also, I find its fairly easy to eavesdrop a PIN on a touchpad when I use my tablet commuting on a subway, but find that this is a reasonable defense against smudge attacks.